# How to call a yml pipline task based on dynamic data

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a repo containing an nx mono repo that produces x number of angular apps. We rely on the affected command to only build apps that have changed which works fine.
What i need to do though is be able to call a set of yml tasks (zip files, publish etc) for each app that was built.

So far i have got to the point of capturing a list of system names in a variable but i cannot find a way to then for example call the ArchiveFiles@2 task for each system. I have seen this done when you have the list of systems as a parameter that you pass into the pipeline and then iterate through using the $ {{ each }} syntax but since our list of systems is dynamic I can't do this.

Comment: How are your pipelines set up? Is it one pipeline for all apps or a pipeline per app with the appropriate triggers?

Comment: It's one pipeline and the nx affected command determines what gets built.

Comment: I believe using a job variable and assigning the list of systems to the variable of the running job might work. Then you can just loop with `${{ each var in variables }}:` syntax